# sending multiple responses for a same request in logic app: ActionResponseAlreadyDefined

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-hdinsight, azure-logic-apps

While running the following Logic App Flow I am getting the Error as

`ActionResponseAlreadyDefined: The execution of template action 'Response_2' is skipped: another response action has already executed.`

[image]
I want to send two different Responses to my HTTP Client Request at the same time from logicapps.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot define responses in parallel branches. How do you foresee to get two HTTP responses from a single HTTP request?

If you want to define different responses, you have to take an IF/THEN logic, and not parallel branches.

If you want to execute two actions in parallel and still have both the responses, you will need to combine both results and send them as a single response.

To achieve that, you may indicate that your action `Response` also depends on `Create or update a template dep..` which is under `hadoopfunctionjson`. Thus you will (kind-of) synchronise the parallel branches and will be able to reference the output from `hadoopfunctionJson` too.

Comment: Hi astaykov, Thanks for your response, I have just sending one response which was combined from all my previous deployment scripts in Logic App Flow.

Answer (score 0):

1. Click "Setting" of your "Response" action.
2. Enable "Asynchronous Response"
   [as in this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/coS01.png)
3. Hit save